# get Chart js tool tips to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, chart.js

I am facing an issue with Chartjs(2.0) tool tips. In my view there are two wrapper DIV elements, one is the container div for the chart js and other is another container with a custom legend

My issue is its hiding tool tips because of my custom legend which is positioned using z-index and top of the chart

I need to get the tool tips to top of my legend

[click to view screen shot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xibkd.jpg)

Sample code of my view

```
<div class="chart-wrapper>
    <canvas id="{{ChartConfig.chartName}}-chart" class="chart"
        chart-data="chartData.counts" chart-labels="chartData.labels"
        chart-options="chartOptions" chart-colors="chartColors" chart-click="openList">
    </canvas>
</div>

<div class="legend-wrapper"
        ng-repeat="segment in legendItems track by $index"
        ng-click="openList(segment.text)">
        <div class="color-swatch"
            ng-style="{background: segment.fillStyle}"></div>
        <div class="item-name">{{ segment.text }}</div>
        <div class="item-value">{{ chartData.counts[segment.index] }}</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi sahil please use the link to view my issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xibkd.jpg

Comment: can you please create a fiddle? Because I need to see the divs html /css and the java script with which you have initialized the chart.

Comment: thank you sahil I have updated my issue with the piece of code but unfortunately I cant make a fiddle of my issue because its little complected.

Comment: try giving .chart-wrapper position:relative and then give z-index higher than that of legend-wrapper. Hope it will help

Comment: @SahilDhir the issue is my legend is clickable after increasing the z-index of the chart the legend goes bottom and cant click on the items . I have increased the chart wrapper width to avoid cutting off tool tips

Comment: ok thats cool then .. happy Coding ;)